# How to get radio button checked value

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to get the checked values of a radio group in meteor js. So far i have come up with this.

**Js**

```
Template.QuizController.events({
  'submit .quiz-ans'(event) {
    // Prevent default browser form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get value from form element
    console.log(event);


  },
});
```

**Html**

```
<template name="QuizQuestion">
<div class="questions">
    <h5 class="white-text">{{question}}</h5>
    <form action="#" class="quiz-ans">
        <ul class="answer-list">
            <li class="answer-items animated out ">
                <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="{{this.order}}q1" />
                <label for="{{this.order}}q1">{{this.q1.value}}</label>
            </li>
            <li class="answer-items animated out ">
                <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="{{this.order}}q2" />
                <label for="{{this.order}}q2">{{this.q2.value}}</label>
            </li>
            <li class="answer-items animated out ">
                <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="{{this.order}}q3"  />
                <label for="{{this.order}}q3">{{this.q3.value}}</label>
            </li>
            <li class="answer-items animated out ">
                <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="{{this.order}}q4"  />
                <label for="{{this.order}}q4">{{this.q4.value}}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="test-controlls">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="action">Next
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
            <span class="quiz-count right">1/10</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</template>
```

I was looking inside the target data but still can find the checked value. this is probably very obvious but I cant figure it out.So help wound be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `event` will contain your `form` element as `event.target`. That will contain all your inputs so you can query them, e.g. using jQuery.

For example:

```
const checked = $(event.target).find("input[name='group1']:checked");
```

If you wanted to get the value attached to that (like "q1") you could then do:

```
checked[0].id;
```

or

```
checked[0].labels[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get radio button checked value by

```
const val= $('input[name=group1]:checked').val();
```